# I cannot somehow POST files on my database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Im trying to make my school project and would like to make a login system and registration system...my login queries are fine but my registration is taking its time...ivev been here for 3-4 hours trying to figure this out im crying right now.... ive done everything....so in my desperate need i asked this community... please provide immediate answers i desperately need it... the problem is... i cannot seem to haul in the data that i type into my form...tahts it...i dont know whats the reason behind

```
if($_POST['registerbtn'])
{
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getconfirmation = $_POST['confirmation'];

            if($getemail){


             if($getuser){

                 if($getpass){

                     if($getconfirmation){

                         if( $getpass === $getconfirmation ){
                             if( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, "."))) {

                                 require("./Connect.php");

                                 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                                 if($numrows == 0){
                                 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                                 if($numrows == 0){

                                      $date = date("F d, Y");
                                      $code = rand();

                                      mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$getuser', '$getemail', '$getpass', '$date' )");
                                      mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                      $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                                     if($numrows == 1){



                                     }else
                                       $errormsg = "An Error Has Occurred. Account Not Processed";


                                 }else
                                     $errormsg ="There is already a user with that email.";


                                 }else
                                     $errormsg ="There is already a user with that username.";


                                 mysql_close();

                             }else
                                 $errormsg = "You must enter a valid email address";

                         }else
                             $errormsg = "Your passwords did not match";


                     }else
                     $errormsg = "Confirm your password";
                 }else
                  $errormsg = "You must enter your password";
             }else
               $errormsg = "You must enter your username";



            }else
             $errormsg = "You must enter your email address";

}





$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>

<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<fieldset>
<legend>Account</legend>
<input type='text' name='user' size='15' value='$getuser'/>:Username<br/>
<input type='text' name='email' size='15'value='$getemail'>:Email<br/>
<input type='password' name='pass' size='15' value=''/>:Passcode<br/>
<input type='password' name='confirmation' size='15' value=''/>:Confirmation<br/>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='EAT ME'/>
</fieldset>
</form>";
  echo "$form";
?>
```

Comment: Where does it go wrong? Which error message are you getting? We need to know which piece of code is causing the issue so we can answer the question easier for you.

Comment: Wow that's some fancy spaghetti code!! =D Hey, maybe `$_POST['registerbtn']` is false, and everything is just skipped.

Comment: @JeremyThille Is it really? why would it?

Comment: I don't know. Why not? How do you know it's not? Debug your code by echoing values here and there. What does `echo $_POST['registerbtn'];` output?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show when you submit the form?

Comment: @Barmar it shows this i dont know waht they are XD im only in 8th gradew trying to learn   array(5) { ["user"]=> string(8) "Myname09" ["email"]=> string(17) "Myemail@gmail.com" ["pass"]=> string(8) "Myname09" ["confirmation"]=> string(8) "Myname09" ["registerbtn"]=> string(6) "EAT ME" }

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille it only displays "eat me" its the value i set for it

Comment: @Jordy Uhm....everything else works fine but the problem lies in if($numrows == 1){}

Comment: @Jordy they seem to execute the commands right before that... and the error code iset in for " if($numrows == 1) { }else echo"whatever i put iin there".... shows up

Comment: Are you sure the values in the `INSERT` query are in the right order? It's best to put the list of columns explicitly, e.g. `INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, ...) VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$email', ...)`. Also, make sure you escape all the values with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Barmar escape all the values with what ? i dont know what they mean

Comment: `$getuser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'])`;'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: None of my comments are solutions to your problem, they're just suggestions for better coding. Make sure you have error reporting enabled, with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Barmar...thank sir for trying to help me...and btw i saw this from a tutorial in youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2NYbEjTzE8&list=PLF99B82E8685AA149&index=13

Comment: i followed everything and yet...poof :(

Comment: @Jordy i was getting the numrows==1 else error msg

Answer (score 0):

if you are submitting form at same page.

```
$form = "<form action='' method='post'>
```

try this..

---

```
if(isset($_POST['registerbtn']))
```

instead of

```
if($_POST['registerbtn'])
```

and
if your Connect.php and registration is in same folder then use `require("Connect.php");` if outside the folder then give proper path

---

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check if the variables are set if not set them to "" except for registerbtn.

Like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registerbtn']))
{
  ...

} else {
  $getuser = $getemail = $errormsg = "";
}





$form = "<form action='./register.php' method='post'>

<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
<fieldset>
<legend>Account</legend>
<input type='text' name='user' size='15' value='$getuser'/>:Username<br/>
<input type='text' name='email' size='15'value='$getemail'>:Email<br/>
<input type='password' name='pass' size='15' value=''/>:Passcode<br/>
<input type='password' name='confirmation' size='15' value=''/>:Confirmation<br/>
<br/>
<input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='EAT ME'/>
</fieldset>
</form>";
  echo "$form";
```

It should work provided there isn't any problem with the db part.

In the one of the if-conditionals viz:

```
if($numrows == 1){
}else
    $errormsg = "An Error Has Occurred. Account Not Processed";
```

This is not needed because the else of `if($numrows == 0 )` takes care of it.

Comment: i tried deleting it...but whenever i submit it only displays a blank error query

Comment: @tramp....im not certain of what im even saying XD im so sorry...i found out that im also using 1pv6 the ::1 thing....along with 127.0.0.1 and localhost....does these mean anything?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 works the same as localhost... Get back to your question... What did it mean when you said "whenever i submit it only displays a blank error query "...??

Comment: Ok... Let's try debugging... before the mysql insert try doing this `echo "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$getuser', '$getemail', '$getpass', '$date' )";`... Let me know the o/p...

Comment: uhm..i tried making a new one...from a new tutorial and he asked me to do this      if (empty($_POST) === flase){
 echo 'Form Submitted';
} it only displays a blank page

Comment: im gonna try what you suggested now

Answer (score 0):

change `<form action='./register.php' method='post'>` to `<form action='' method='post'> or <form action='#' method='post'>`

Comment: I was wondering... Is `if("EAT ME")` considered as non-false, so true?

Comment: change <form action='./register.php' method='post'> to <form action='#' method='post'>

Comment: @AkshayaMoorthy none whatsoever

Comment: @FawnFrauscht , check ur db connection is ok

Comment: assign your db connection statement in a variable and echo it, if connection fails it returns NULL, you can check the validity of each statement this way

Comment: @AkshayaMoorthy ive recently made a login page with the same Connections.php containing my db connections scripts and its working...my problem is that i cannot send data to the database...its so queer...ive been staring at my screen and lookinf for solutions for 6 hours XD i think my mom is mad at me...